# LoopbackJS Upgrade 2.29.1 to ^2.30.x mocha API tests broken Promise.join is not a function

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, loopbackjs, bluebird, es6-promise

We have been pinned on loopback version [2.29.1](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/releases/tag/v2.29.1) for a few months after a reordering of PUT/PATCH endpoints broke other tests. I am attempting to upgrade to the latest 2.x version using semver ^[2.29.1](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/releases/tag/v2.29.1), but I'm seeing a strange breakage of an API test when I upgrade explicitly to [2.30.0](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/releases/tag/v2.30.0). Anything higher than [2.29.1](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/releases/tag/v2.29.1) breaks this way.

We are replacing the native Promise library with bluebird inside `server.js` using

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot     = require('loopback-boot');
var Promise  = global.Promise = require('bluebird');
...
```

Our mocha tests use `supertest` to call the API and assert results.

Using [2.29.1](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/releases/tag/v2.29.1), everything runs fine.

In one instance of an Org model we are using `Promise.join()` to aggregate the results of a couple calls.

After upgrading loopback to [2.30.0](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/releases/tag/v2.30.0) (explicit), the test no longer works and gives the error

```
Promise.join is not a function
```

Nothing is changed except the loopback version bump from [2.29.1](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/releases/tag/v2.29.1) to [2.30.0](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/releases/tag/v2.30.0).

Same result with all versions above [2.29.1](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/releases/tag/v2.29.1) that I've tried so far.

How did the loopback lib change to no longer pick up the bluebird library override when running mocha tests?

Going to pore over a [2.29.1...2.30.0](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/compare/v2.29.1...v2.30.0) comparison to see if I can find any smoking guns. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: This likely has something to do with Bluebird and the version you're installing, seeing as [`v2.29.1...v2.30.0`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/compare/v2.29.1...v2.30.0#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2) upgraded Bluebird. (What's odd is that it's in loopback's `devDependencies`. I would take a peek into your `node_modules` directory and see if you can determine what version of Bluebird you have installed vs. what version you want.) Also note that [loopback doesn't seem to actually *use* `Promise.join` anywhere](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/search?q=join&utf8=✓).

Comment: Thanks. We've got bluebird `^3.4.7` as our app dependency and the updated loopback has `^3.4.1`, so they should resolve to the same version. But isn't that irrelevant and `npm install` will ignore devDeps in loopback? `3.4.7` is installed in `node_modules`, which is what we want.